# Item height in the mvxcrecyclerview

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a question about the items height in a recyclerview, here is my screen
[image]

Is it possible to have the same height for each rows like that for example:

[image]

So the first one has to have the same height of the second and the third the same as the 4th one.
Currently I used wrap-content that's why the height is changing regarding the content of the cardview but I would like to use smt dynamic if it possible and not put a fixed height.

Here is my code

```
    <MvvmCross.DroidX.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewSalary"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lblSalary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/cell_tool_cardview"
        app:MvxBind="ItemClick OpenTool;ItemsSource SalarisToolItems"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        app:spanCount="2"/>
```

and the itemtemplate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin2"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin2"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin2"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin1"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(Available)">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin4"
        android:background="@color/lightBlue">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayoutCellTool"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgTool"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:tint="@color/blue"
                app:MvxBind="DrawableName ImageDrawable"/>

        </FrameLayout>
  
        <TextView         
            android:id="@+id/lblTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin3"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin3"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
            android:textSize="@dimen/t4"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/frameLayoutCellTool"
            app:MvxBind="Text Title"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/t2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/mulish_regular"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lblTitle"
            app:MvxBind="Text SubTitle; Visibility InvertedVisibility(IsEmptySubTitle)"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Anyone has an idea ? Thanks

Comment: because of this in your cardview ```android:layout_height="wrap_content"``` change to size or set layout weight.

Comment: Set every text view minlines 3 or something and alignment center as well... You'll get even card